# Best way to convert Locale specific String to BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have to convert a German locale formatted `String` to a `BigDecimal`. However, I'm struggling with the best solution.

The following code shows my problem:

```
    String numberString = "2.105,88";

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    try {
        Number parsed = nf.parse(numberString);
        BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(parsed.toString());
        System.out.println(bd1.toString());

        BigDecimal bd2 = new BigDecimal(parsed.doubleValue());
        System.out.println(bd2);

        BigDecimal bd3 = new BigDecimal(numberString);
        System.out.println(bd3);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The outpout of this is

> 2105.88
>
> 2105.8800000000001091393642127513885498046875
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException
>       at java.math.BigDecimal.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.math.BigDecimal.(Unknown Source)
>       at test.BigDecimalTest.main(BigDecimalTest.java:22)

The first output is correct, but it doesn't really make sense to convert a `String` to a `Number` (`Double` to be precise), then back to a `String` again and then into a specific type of `Number`, `BigDecimal`.

The second output is incorrect, but could be solved by setting the scale of the `BigDecimal`. However, the amount of digits is not always known.

The third output is obviously not what I'm looking for.

My question: What would be the best way? Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It seems like there is no other way since `java.Lang.Number` doesn't have a method which returns a `BigDecimal` type. Anyway it makes sense because `BigDecimal` only accepts strings which are properly formatted not like `"2.105,88"` but like `"2105.88"`.

Let me show your my code:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;
public class JavaMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String numberString = "2.105,88";
        //using casting
        try {
            DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
            df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
            BigDecimal bd = (BigDecimal) df.parseObject(numberString);
            System.out.println(bd.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //your way short version
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
        try {
            BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(nf.parse(numberString).toString());
            System.out.println(bd1.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String numberStringFixed = "2105.88";
        //direct string formatted
        System.out.println(new BigDecimal(numberStringFixed));;     
        //direct but erroneous way if the string is not formatted
        System.out.println(new BigDecimal(numberString));;
        
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: As for "properly formatted"...  `2.105,88` is in fact entirely properly formatted in a bunch of locales... And in those locales, `2105.88` is not proper at all. What this whole ordeal would need is a Locale argument for the BigDecimal constructor...

Comment: @ppeterka you're confusing presentation vs. logic when referring to "properly formatted". "2.105,88" isn't computer notation in any fashion. That's a presentation issue. It wouldn't make sense to make every conceivable mechanism for dealing with numbers require having a locale parameter purely to handle presentation.

Comment: @NathanCrause I disagree. Converting something from and to a String always should require proper locale. You might not have encountered the issues that stem from the decimal character being different in various locals but it can break stuff in spectacular ways if not accounted for.

Comment: @NathanCrause also curious: how would you solve the issue then, what should be the default locale?

Comment: This way is not good, so if you pass "0.001" result will be 1

Answer (score 33):

`DecimalFormat` has a method called [`setParseBigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setParseBigDecimal%28boolean%29) that causes `parse()` to return a `BigDecimal`. You just need to cast the returned `Number`.

```
    String numberString = "2.105,88";

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    if (nf instanceof DecimalFormat) {
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) nf;
        df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
        BigDecimal parsed = (BigDecimal) df.parse(numberString);

        System.out.println(parsed);
    }
```

Output:

> 2105.88

`setParseBigDecimal` was introduced in Java 1.5.

Comment: @JarettMillard In truth `DecimalFormat`  have, `NumberFormat` have not this method

Comment: @deFreitas `NumberFormat` is an abstract class. The docs for `DecimalFormat` explicitly tell you to create instances of it with `NumberFormat.getInstance()`.

Comment: "NumberFormat is an abstract class" which doesn't have such method, meaning you have to cast back to DecimalFormat the result of the factory method.