# Reformat From String into Decimal

Tags: java, double, type-conversion

i had data = 137500 as double variable, and i converted with DecimalFormat into Rp.137.500,00 and set to a textfield.
how do i reformat from texfield to 137500. cz i want to multiply from that.

Comment: Well have you tried using `DecimalFormat.parse` to reverse the effect of `DecimalFormat.format`? (I don't see why `regex`, `desktop` and `desktop-application` are particularly relevant here, btw.)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: cz i think my problem could be fix with regex, and i'm developing in desktop-application. i'm sorry btw cz this is my first question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836647/best-way-to-convert-locale-specific-string-to-bigdecimal

Comment: Note that it's a bad idea to use `double` for amounts of money, because `double` has limited precision. People won't like it if their amount of money becomes incorrect because of rounding errors.

Comment: thanks for advice , so what sould i use?? int?? or long??

Answer (score 0):

Is your `double` variable still **in scope**?

If yes - just use it.

If not, change it's visibility and/or, create a `get...()` method to access it.

It's always a good idea to numbers in an appropriate numeric type and do formatting when it becomes necessary.

While it should be possible to extract a sub-string with just the number part and then use `Double.parseDouble()` method for conversion, I still do not see a point of doing it.

Comment: no.., i just use local variable and i initiate with multiply value from some textfield, and set into value textfield with DecimalFormat. but i don't know to reformat.

Comment: Then make it a `private` variable of your class and create `public getVar()` method to access it.