# Optional plus sign with java.text.DecimalFormat

Tags: java, number-formatting

I would like to parse decimal numbers in Java with plus sign, minus sign or no sign and get an instance of `BigDecimal`. This can be achieved simply by calling constructor `new BigDecimal(string)`. It produces appropriate results for all of the following strings:

```
"1", "12", "123", "123.0", "+123.0", "-123.0", "+123", "-123"
```

However, I need to parse the strings according a specific locale, i.e. with comma decimal separator. Is there a way to parse all these numbers with respect to a particular locale?

I tried `NumberFormat` and `DecimalFormat` but cannot configure it appropriately.

```
final DecimalFormat valueParser = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("cs"));
valueParser.setParseBigDecimal(true);
```

Such `valueParser` does not accept the plus sign. There is an option to set a pattern to `DecimalFormat`. However, can the plus sign be specified as optional in the pattern?

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836647/best-way-to-convert-locale-specific-string-to-bigdecimal

Comment: @Garry In the suggested stackoverflow question, `NumberFormat` / `DecimalFormat` is used. However, the optional plus sign is not addressed.

Comment: What is the difference between number with plus sign and no sign?

Comment: @Garry `123` and `+123` have both the same value but I want to accept both formats like `new BigDecimal(String)` does. However, `DecimalFormat` can either be configured to accept positive values with mandatory plus sign or it can be configured to accept positive values without plus sign. It cannot be configured to handle an optional plus sign.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a DecimalFormat that accepts or better requires a leading "+".

```
    DecimalFormat f (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale(...));
    f.setPositivePrefix("+");
    f.parse("+123");
```

However the prefix is **not** optional therefore it does not help your case.
As a very simple solution, why don't you check the (trimmed) string if starts with a '+' character and in that case cut of the leading '+' before you pass the string to the DecimalFormats parse method.

Comment: oh those suckers, why does it format 0 to "+0", 0 is neither positive nor negative number