# Format string into BigDecimal

Tags: java, string, parsing, formatting

I'm parsing out a bunch of numbers from a text-file.

I've isolated the number: `4711,17` from the file which is supposed to be converted into BigDecimal for further processing. (note the comma)

But i am unable to convert it. I get parseExceptions.

```
public BigDecimal amount; //variable
while((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) { //reading from file
    amount = new BigDecimal(line.substring(17,30)); //parsing out the number
}
```

Is it because of the comma or what is going on here? (I am unable to change it from a comma to a dot)

Thanks

---

First line in output looks like this:

`O5555 5555555555       4711,17         420110315SEK`

Comment: paste the full line

Comment: @Roushan updated

Comment: Beyond that, such things can also depend on your locale. If your JVM for some reason uses say a US local ... then "," is not seen as comma separator!

Comment: And then: isolate such things: have a little method that *parses* the line and returns the isolated number as string. And pass the result of that into BigDecimal. Do **one** thing at a time (also much easier to test)!

Comment: @GhostCat I've tried parsing the number into a string and then trimmed away the whitespace. then tried converting it to BigDecimal. No luck. I've also tried `DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
      decimalFormatSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
       
       DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
       format.setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
       amount = new BigDecimal(line.substring(17, 30));`

Comment: Always update your question instead of putting so many details into comments! Go step by step: first make sure that the **incoming** string looks as expected. Again: first make sure the parsed number looks exactly as you expect it. Then worry about passing it to that ctor.

Comment: @Joel Do you still have an issue? If your problem has been resolved, don't hesitate to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues here:

## Extraneous whitespaces

You are trying to parse the following `String`: `"      4711,17"`.

You need to **trim** it in order to remove the leading and trailing whitespace characters, using `String#trim`.

## Using comma (`,`) as a decimal separator

Just like parsing `Date`s, currencies and even numbers are somewhat `Locale`-dependant. In some (many) countries, the comma (`,`) is used as a separator for thousands, and the dot (`.`) indicates decimals.

Thus, you'll have to specify the `Locale` you're working with for your computer to interpret this `String` the same way you do (or assume the default `Locale` is the one you want).

For instance, let's use the `Locale.FRANCE` locale, which **does** use `,` as a separator for decimals:

```
//                                                  ',' indicates decimals
//                                                      v           v
final NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
final String line = "O5555 5555555555       4711,17         420110315SEK";
final Number parsed = formatter.parse(line.substring(17, 30).trim());
//                                                          ^     ^
//                                                          trimmed
```

Using the snippet above, you'll be left with a `Number` whose value is the one you want :)

Since you're looking for a `BigDecimal` though, I'd simply use `BigDecimal.valueOf(parsed .doubleValue())` to 'convert' it, like so:

```
final BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.valueOf(formatter.parse(line.substring(17, 30).trim()).doubleValue());
```

Incorporating this into your piece of code would give:

```
BigDecimal amount;
while((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
    amount = BigDecimal.valueOf(formatter.parse(line.substring(17, 30).trim()).doubleValue());
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to produce here, but unfortunately this doesn't give me `,` but `.` instead. Or is that the fault of System.out.println ?

Comment: Yes, it's just printed out `"4711.17"` ! The value is the right one! If you add `0.83` to it, you get `4712.0`.

Answer (score 0):

using trim remove the whitespaces from substring:

```
String line="O5555 5555555555       4711,17         420110315SEK";
 DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
 symbols.setGroupingSeparator(',');
String pattern = "#,##";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern, symbols);
decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);
 BigDecimal amount = null;
            try {
                amount = (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse(line.substring(17,30).trim());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(amount);
```

## out

`471117`

Comment: Sorry, but as stated in the question... I cannot change from comma to dots (or remove them)

Comment: but ultimately you will get the same value,

Comment: Sure, but it kinda defeats the purpose of being fed data in a certain way then altering it. If I could change the format of the files, i would.

Comment: precisely use locales - or replace substring comma into dot. In Polish reality (where comma is traditional separator, but many data has dots) I prefer for many reasons replace

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the number you receive is not en_US locale, since it uses commas to separate decimal part, so you can use different locale to parse it.

```
String numStr = "O5555 5555555555       4711,17         420110315SEK".substring(17, 30).trim();
NumberFormat nf = DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(nf.parseObject(numStr).toString());
```

More info here: [Best way to convert Locale specific String to BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836647/best-way-to-convert-locale-specific-string-to-bigdecimal)

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Format.parseObject(String) failed
 at java.text.Format.parseObject(Format.java:245)`

Comment: @Joel it's probably a different line from the file - the code example that i put on my answer works with no exceptions. Try printing out the numStr before parsing it to see which line causes exception